localhost Vite proxy does not work in vue 3
I am unable to get a vue proxy to work using the vite.config.ts  configuration.
Note: To keep things simple I have everything running on http for now
the environment:
Vue 3 front end connecting to a c# rest api on my development machine.
The vue front end runs on http://localhost:3000 and the c# api runs on http://localhost:3001
Summary of problem
If i make a fetch call from vue to the backend using the actual host name and port this works just fine
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/AuthenticationCookie/Login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(loginData)

})
But if i try it using a vite proxy to the url '/go' the proxy never gets hit and vue just receives a 404.
 const response = await fetch('/go/api/AuthenticationCookie/Login', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(loginData)
 })

proxy setup in vite.config.ts
 export default defineConfig({
 server: {
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/go': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3001', // your backend url
                changeOrigin: false,
                secure: false, // Set to true if your backend uses HTTPS
                configure: (proxy, _options) => { 
                    proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
                        console.log('proxy error', err);
                    });
                    proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, _req, _res) => {
                        console.log('proxy request to target', _req.method, _req.url);
                    })
                }
            }
        }
 },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})


In your proxy set up, change
changeOrigin: false

to
changeOrigin: true

so that the Host header matches that of the target and not http://localhost:3001
EDIT: '/go' remains part of the URL sent to the back end, meaning the URL is sent as '/go/api/AuthenticationCookie/Login'.
Try removing it by adding:
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/go/, '')

after
  changeOrigin: true


thank you I have tried it both ways and same result.    It started as true and was failing so i flipped it to false to see if it would have any impact.  I just flipped it back and tested it again - same 404 result.

'/go' remains part of the URL sent to the back end, meaning the URL is sent as '/go/api/AuthenticationCookie/Login'.
Try removing it by adding:
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/go/, '')

after
  changeOrigin: true


rewrite rule for the win. Once i realized the console.logs are not actually going to the browser console at all and instead are showing up in the command window visual studio launches for vue then i was able to see the proxy firing and debug it out. the rewrite rule is needed to get the correct path as you stated.  - thanks for the assist.

I was able to finally get this to work after 5 hours of debugging so hopefully this is helpful.
I have seen many other people post about the vite proxy and not get it functional.
Here are the 2 items that allowed me to get this function
1 - awareness that the console.logs do not log into the browser window/console.
2 - adding very detailed console.logs shown below.
1 - console.logs
If you are using visual studio( which I was), the largest problem i had was that i could not tell that the proxy actually was firing even when it was firing because the console.log messages never appeared in the browser being launched by VS
Instead visual studio launches a command window behind the scenes and in the command window (which often launches behind your other windows) the console.logs were getting hit.
2 - I added a log of console.log messages logging out everything i could.
Here is final code which worked for me with vite and vue 3.  The code below provides detailed logs to allow anyone having issues to see what is going on.
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        port:3000,
        proxy: {
            '/go': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3001',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/go/, ''),
                configure: (proxy, _options) => {
                    proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res) => {
                        const originalUrl = req.url;
                        const rewrittenUrl = proxyReq.path; // This should give you the rewritten path
                        //const queryParams = req.query; // Assuming query parameters are available in req.query
                        const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();

                        console.log('Proxying request:', {
                            method: req.method,
                            originalUrl: originalUrl,
                            rewrittenUrl: rewrittenUrl,
                            headers: req.headers,
                            //queryParams: queryParams,
                            timestamp: timestamp
                        });
                    });
                    proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, res) => {
                        console.log('Received response from target:', proxyRes.statusCode);
                    });
                    proxy.on('error', (err, req, res) => {
                        console.error('Proxy error:', err);
                    });
                }

